# how do you input a text file into dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Im completely new to python, i have tried to look it up but im still not sure how you do it.

right now my text file look like this:

```
'a':bla bla bla
'b':bla bla bla
'c':bla bla bla
```

I wish to read this file to a dictionary such that column 1 is the key and column 2 is the value, i.e:

```
d = {'a':bla bla bla, 'b':bla bla bla, 'c':bla bla bla}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question is too vague.  If you want help you will need to show some effort and ask a more specific question. See [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry for the confusion

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and edit your question with [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

A manual method in python3:

```
a_dict = {}  # To store the values in
with open('file.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        entry = line.split(":")  # split for key, value
        # store into dict, need to strip ' from the key and \n from value
        a_dict[entry[0].strip("' ")] = entry[1].strip()

print(a_dict)  # Show the results
```